# Estimate the value of a sigmoid function over expectation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I would like to estimate the function value of the sigmoid over an expectation, that is:
\begin{equation}
\sigma(\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[f(x)]),
\end{equation}
where $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$, and $p(x)$ is the one we only access its samples but cannot evaluate its density.

To estimate $\sigma(\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[f(x)])$, we could use $\sigma(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i))$, but it is biased. My question is, how could we define an unbiased estimator.

Comment: You need to postulate a specific family of distributions governing the random samples $x_i.$  What would that be?

Comment: @whube Let's discuss the case when p(x) is Bernoulli or categorical distribution

Comment: The solution to that is [well known and instructive](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+polynomial+unbias*).

Answer (score 1):

No unbiased estimator exists, when $p(x)$ is Categorical distribution:

[Unbiased estimator of exponential of measure of a set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422696/unbiased-estimator-of-exponential-of-measure-of-a-set/422697#422697)

[For the binomial distribution, why does no unbiased estimator exist for $1/p$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/for-the-binomial-distribution-why-does-no-unbiased-estimator-exist-for-1-p)

Thank @whuber for the given link.